# Virtualbox on Amazon AWS using 64-bit guest OS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, azure, virtualbox

Yes, I understand this is silly, wasteful, and completely wrong, however, it is somewhat possible.

I'm essentially doubly-virtualizing myself. The Host OS is Windows Dataserver (2016) 64 bit.

When launching Virtualbox after successfull installation, the only options are for 32-bit guest OS'es.

Since its a virtual-world, there is obviously no way to enable VT or Virtualization in the BIOS.

Hyper-V is not running.

Is there any way to run 64 bit instances inside Virtualbox on Amazon-AWS?

TIA...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure has [support for nested virtualization](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2017/07/how-to-setup-nested-virtualization-in-microsoft-azure/) for some specific instance types where you can launch a guest operating system on top of your virtual machine.

AWS has full support to the nested virtualization only in bare metal instance types. I have tried to install Hyper-V on top of general purpose instance, it failed to emulate a virtual device. But I have installed [openstack](https://github.com/rkkrishnaa/openstack-ocata) which requires KVM hypervisor and created virtual machines on top of general purpose instances. We have to do some changes in network stack to access the nested virtualized vm based on the OS distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Your desire is **not** "silly, wasteful, and completely wrong"!  Take a look at this [exact feature request](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) on VB.

Over 11 years it goes from "silly" to "essential" and now implemented for **Intel chips**.  Sorry not for AMD chips yet I guess.  Because I need to do the same thing, but it's not supported yet.

Answer (score -1):

Why run a nested vm and not the software on the main instance.But to ans. your question no you cannot emulate a Vt. I read something about xenconsole having some ability like this.